# how do I find differences between similar strings?

Tags: r, string, string-comparison

I have a vector of strings (file names to be exact).

```
pav <- c("Sn_4Khz_3W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_",
         "Sn_4Khz_4W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_",
         "Sn_4Khz_4W_50_130_02_30cm_101mm_")
```

I'm looking for a simple way to find difference between these strings.

```
`> char_position_fun(pav) # gives unique character position
[1] 9 12 13 `


`> char_diff_fun(pav) # removes matching components (position and value)
[1] 3_4_5  4_4_5  4_5_0`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I decided to split all letters and create a data frame for each string containing position and letter information. Then, for each position, I checked if there is one unique letter or not. If FALSE, that suggests that not all letters are identical. Finally, subset the data frame with a logical condition. In this way, you can see position and letter information together.

```
library(tidyverse)

strsplit(mytext, split = "") %>% 
map_dfr(.x = .,
        .f = function(x) enframe(x, name = "position", value = "word"),
        .id = "id") %>% 
group_by(position) %>% 
mutate(check = n_distinct(word) == 1) %>% 
filter(check == FALSE)

  id    position word  check
  <chr>    <int> <chr> <lgl>
1 1            9 3     FALSE
2 1           12 4     FALSE
3 1           13 5     FALSE
4 2            9 4     FALSE
5 2           12 4     FALSE
6 2           13 5     FALSE
7 3            9 4     FALSE
8 3           12 5     FALSE
9 3           13 0     FALSE
```

If you want to have the outcome as you described, you can add a bit more operation.

```
strsplit(mytext, split = "") %>% 
map_dfr(.x = .,
        .f = function(x) enframe(x, name = "position", value = "word"),
        .id = "id") %>% 
group_by(position) %>% 
mutate(check = n_distinct(word) == 1) %>% 
filter(check == FALSE) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
summarize_at(vars(position:word),
             .funs = list(~paste0(., collapse = "_")))

  id    position word 
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1 1     9_12_13  3_4_5
2 2     9_12_13  4_4_5
3 3     9_12_13  4_5_0
```

**DATA**

```
mytext <- c("Sn_4Khz_3W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_", "Sn_4Khz_4W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_", 
"Sn_4Khz_4W_50_130_02_30cm_101mm_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

At first, we can invert strings from UTF8 to Int, i.e.,

```
z <- Map(utf8ToInt,v)
```

- the positions of differences

```
pos <- unique(unlist(outer(z,z,FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y) which(x!=y)))))

> pos
[1]  9 12 13
```

- the chars that are different:

```
word <- Map(function(x) paste(intToUtf8(x[p],multiple = T),collapse = "_"),z)

> word
$Sn_4Khz_3W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_
[1] "3_4_5"

$Sn_4Khz_4W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_
[1] "4_4_5"

$Sn_4Khz_4W_50_130_02_30cm_101mm_
[1] "4_5_0"
```

**DATA**

```
v <- c("Sn_4Khz_3W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_", "Sn_4Khz_4W_45_130_02_30cm_101mm_", 
            "Sn_4Khz_4W_50_130_02_30cm_101mm_")
```